# Spring Integration DSL, If mq message(contains list of Addresses) processing failed and one address its not proceeding with the left address processin

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a Message over IBM MQ, message contains list.

I have written a spring Integration Flow like the following

**ListenerContainer**

```
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer addressProcessorListenerContainer(
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
             String queueName,
             int consumers,
            PipelineErrorHandler pipelineErrorHandler
    ) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setSessionTransacted(true);
        container.setPubSubDomain(false);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(consumers);
        container.setDestinationName(queueName);
        container.setErrorHandler(pipelineErrorHandler);
        return container;
    }
```

**Error handler**

```
@Component
public class PipelineErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PipelineErrorHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred during pipeline execution, It will retry now", t);
    }
}
```

**Parent IntegrationFLow**

```
  @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processAddressFlow(DefaultMessageListenerContainer addressProcessorListenerContainer) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(addressProcessorListenerContainer))
                //Router to decide which channel to follow based on function
                .route(Message.class, this::hasMessageBreachedItsMaxRedeliveryThreshold,
                        router -> router.channelMapping(true, "max-redelivery-threshold-channel").applySequence(true)
                                .channelMapping(false, "process-address-channel"))
                .get();
    }
```

**Below is the channel to process addresses**

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow processAddressEventFlow(
                                                       EventTypeFilter eventTypeFilter,
                                                       ) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("process-address-events-channel")
                
                .filter(eventTypeFilter, spec -> spec.id("processAddressEventFlow.eventTypeFilter"))
                .split(spec -> spec.id("processAddressEventFlow.split"))
                .channel("process-address-event-channel")
                .get();
    }
```

Above channel splits list of addresses and pass it to the "process-address-events-channel" channel

**Final Channel to call dao to update address into DB**

```
   public IntegrationFlow addressUpdateFlow(AddressUpdateDao addressUpdateDao,
                                             MessageSourceSystemFilter messageSourceSystemFilter) {
       return IntegrationFlows.from("process-address-event-channel")

              
               .handle(AddressUpdateDao.class, addressUpdateDao, spec -> spec.id("addressUpdateFlow.addressUpdateFlow"))

               .log()
               .get();
   }
```

**Problem Statement:**
Exception raised by dao(eg: SQLException) during processing of one address is passed to parent channel and hence message is committed back to MQ and retry triggered.

Expected scenario: I want to commit message back to MQ with error once processing of all message in the list is done.

Tried using errorchannel and error handler at container level but didn't work.

Exception raised by dao(eg: SQLException) during processing of one address is passed to parent channel and hence message is committed back to MQ and retry triggered.

Expected scenario: I want to commit message back to MQ with error once processing of all message in the list is done.

Comment: Please, clarify: you want to process all items independently of error, but still would like to have that error back, even if you got several of them?

Comment: Hey @ArtemBilan I want to process all messages independent of error and at the end I want to send message back to mq with error flag so that retry can happen. With retry since underlying query is atomic it will not add more updates to already updated record but it will try to update the errored addresses.

Answer (score 0):

OK. According to your explanation you would like to have an error handling per splitted item. And looks like if there is an error you'd like to send some specific message to the MQ. See if `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` on that your `.handle(AddressUpdateDao.class,`  can help you somehow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#expression-advice

Comment: Thank you @Artem, sorry for the late acknowledgment I got deviated from this task. I added this and now I can process each address available the single message even though if there is an error for any of the message. But at the end message is committed to the MQ with success and retry is not triggering. In my case I want to trigger redelivery as well after processing entire list of addresses if there is an error with any address processing.

Comment: Well, the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` does not swallow an exception by default, so I'm not what is going on else. You need to configure a `failureChannel` to send an error for processing and compensation and let that exception to be re-thrown back to the `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` for rollback and re-delivery.

Comment: Thank you @Artem for quick response. The solution you shared - that works fine and satisfy the usecase of suppressing the exception raised during processing of each list item in a message. However I need to add one more behavior where if any of the List item inside a message is failed message needs to be send for redelivery after processing all list items. eg: If in a Message we have a List of address having three addresses and during processing of second address if we get an error it should do the following steps A)

Comment: following steps A) it should continue to process third address and B) After processing last address which is third address it should cascade the error to the Container (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) Error handler so that message redelivery can be triggered.

Comment: Yeah... That's not possible with transactions: we cannot rollback just a part of consumed data. You may consider to use a `manual` acknowledgement for JMS: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/jms/using.html#jms-mdp-simple